# How to format a Map<Entity,integer> in json payload

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to send an entity "order" from a client to Rest/Api Spring Boot
Back-End.
In my `OrderEntity`, contains a Map of buy the product of that order.

we' re trying with postman software to generate a correct JSON string who want to attach in body with post request.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "product.order", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order.id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product.id")
@Column(name = "quantity")
//@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = ProdottoMapSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = ProdottoMapDeserializer.class)
```

**OrderEntity**

```
public OrderEntity(Map<ProductEntity, Integer> product, ClientEntity cliente,Integer id, String data, Float totale, String fattura) {
        this.product = product;
        this.client = client;
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.totale = totale;
        this.fattura = fattura;
    }
@ManyToOne
private ClientEntity cliente;
```

**ProductEntity**

```
public ProductEntity(Integer id, String nome, String descrizione, String categoria, Float prezzo, String foto,
            Integer quantitaMagazzino, Integer spedizione_veloce) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
        this.foto = foto;
        this.quantitaMagazzino = quantitaMagazzino;
        this.spedizione_veloce = spedizione_veloce;
    }
```

we trying with json in a post request, with this type of body:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "data": "2019-07-11 00:00:00",
    "totale": null,
    "fattura": null,
    "product": {
        "ProductEntity{id=4, nome='oneplus 6t', descrizione='smartphone', categoria='elettronica', prezzo=500.0, foto='', quantitaMagazzino=4, spedizione_veloce=0}": 2
    },
    "cliente": {
        "id": 3
    }
}
```

the field "product" has an error, we write in a bad format,
this is the kind of problem:

> "status": 400,
>   "error": "Bad Request",
>   "message": "JSON parse error: For input string: \"ProductEntity{id=4, nome='oneplus 6t', descrizione='smartphone', categoria='elettronica', prezzo=500.0, foto='', quantitaMagazzino=4, spedizione_veloce=0}\"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

and this is my post request:

```
 @PostMapping("/postorder") //PROVA aggiunge un ordine 
 public ResponseEntity<?> postOrder(@RequestBody OrderEntity order){

     orderRepository.save(ordine);


     return new ResponseEntity<>(Collections.singletonMap("id", ordine.getId()),HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

Comment: you can try gson `String jsonMap = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(map);`

Comment: @JsonDeserialize can do the trick. For more: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `:` in the ProductEntity which is why it can't be parsed as an obj in mapping. Try and let me know if it solves the problem, I haven't tested it.

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "data": "2019-07-11 00:00:00",
    "totale": null,
    "fattura": null,
    "product": {
        "ProductEntity: {id=4, nome='oneplus 6t', descrizione='smartphone', categoria='elettronica', prezzo=500.0, foto='', quantitaMagazzino=4, spedizione_veloce=0}": 2
    },
    "cliente": {
        "id": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for trying to help me, i tried with : 
but i had the same problem, maybe i must change toString method?
i don t have any idea how to write in body json format this product

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ProductEntity is annotated with @JsonDeserialize and use this JSON and see if it works

```
  {
    "id": 10,
    "data": "2019-07-11 00:00:00",
    "totale": null,
    "fattura": null,
    "product": {
        "{id=4, nome='oneplus 6t', descrizione='smartphone', categoria='elettronica', prezzo=500.0, foto='', quantitaMagazzino=4, spedizione_veloce=0}": 2
     },
     "cliente": {
         "id": 3
     }
 }
```